# JAXB marshalling of nullable abstract class

Tags: xml, jaxb, abstract, nullable, null

Hello i have problem with marshalling of null abstract class, for example i have:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "envelop ", propOrder = {animal})
class Envelop {    
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
public Animal animal;    
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Animal")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    Cat.class,
    Dog.class
})
public abstract class Animal {

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Dog", propOrder = {
   ...
})
public class Dog extend Animal {...}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Cat", propOrder = {
   ...
})
public class Cat extend Animal {...}
```

So the problem that if do not set anything to animal in envelop, it is marshalled into xml like

```
<animal xsi:nil="true"/>
```

But i need xsi:type.

```
<animal xsi:type="Cat" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

So how i could say to jaxb set some default xsi:type if field is null?? 
If field not null it works ok
For null fields with normal class it woked correctly, but what to do with abstract??

Comment: if it is null then how can it type be determined? Why do you need it in a first place, a null value is just a luck of value. Dog dog = null works as fine as Cat cat = null., what do you need the type ifnormation for.

Comment: Its because of server validation error. It looks not right but i cant change server, so for null value it need type anyway. So i need to place some default type if value null.